# Is acquire(time,unit) method expected to return false when zookeeper is not available?seems that it would hang up

Tags: apache-curator

```
InterProcessMutex zLock=new InterProcessMutex(curatorFramework,lockPath);
zlock.acquire(time,unit);
```

just a simple example. I try to test the Network jitter problem, so I start the service,connect zookeeper and start the curator client, and then disable the network.
after that, I create a request which would call the zlock.acquire(time,unit).
It shows that the request return error response  at least 1min later.
to debug the codes,the program stop in "createsTheLock" method.
In fact, I guess the expectation is to return false when zookeeper is not available.

Thanks for answerring the question!

update the question:
It's the base setting:

```
RetryPolicy retryPolicy=new ExponentialBackoffRetry(1000,3);

CuratorFramework curatorFramework= CuratorFrameworkFactory.builder().connectionTimeoutMs(15000).sessionTimeoutMs(60000).connectString(CommonConstant.ZK_CONNECT_HOSTS).retryPolicy(retryPolicy).build();
```

and it's the log:

```
    2020-08-09 10:27:12.582  INFO 91181 --- [224.71.42:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn          : Opening socket connection to server 10.224.71.42/10.224.71.42:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2020-08-09 10:27:12.582 ERROR 91181 --- [224.71.42:2181)] o.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO   : Unable to open socket to 10.224.71.42/10.224.71.42:2181
2020-08-09 10:27:12.582  INFO 91181 --- [224.71.42:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn          : Socket error occurred: 10.224.71.42/10.224.71.42:2181: Network is unreachable
2020-08-09 10:27:13.456 ERROR 91181 --- [tor-Framework-0] o.a.c.f.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl        : Background operation retry gave up

org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:102) ~[zookeeper-3.5.6.jar:3.5.6]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.checkBackgroundRetry(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:851) [curator-framework-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.performBackgroundOperation(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:999) [curator-framework-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.backgroundOperationsLoop(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:952) [curator-framework-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.access$300(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:66) [curator-framework-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl$4.call(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:342) [curator-framework-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_241]

2020-08-09 10:27:13.457 ERROR 91181 --- [tor-Framework-0] o.a.c.f.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl        : Background retry gave up

org.apache.curator.CuratorConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.performBackgroundOperation(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:981) [curator-framework-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.backgroundOperationsLoop(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:952) [curator-framework-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.access$300(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:66) [curator-framework-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl$4.call(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:342) [curator-framework-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_241]

2020-08-09 10:27:14.684  INFO 91181 --- [26.102.59:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn          : Opening socket connection to server 10.226.102.59/10.226.102.59:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2020-08-09 10:27:14.684 ERROR 91181 --- [26.102.59:2181)] o.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO   : Unable to open socket to 10.226.102.59/10.226.102.59:2181
2020-08-09 10:27:14.684  INFO 91181 --- [26.102.59:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn          : Socket error occurred: 10.226.102.59/10.226.102.59:2181: Network is unreachable
```

The request just hang up until 59s later, then return response;

Comment: I'm sorry but it's hard to understand your question. But, it seems you're asking if lock.acquire() will return false if the network is unavailable? This will depend on your retry policy. I'd need to see what RetryPolicy you're using and also the Curator/ZooKeeper logs.

Comment: @Randgalt Yeah, that is what I ask. And I updated the question above, thanks a lot.

Comment: So, it will retry 3 times on network problems and then throw an exception on the 4th. The lock result is when the network is fine - i.e. it will wait n units until the lock is available. If the network is down and retries expire and exception is thrown.

Comment: @Randgalt Can I understand like that: suppose lock.acuire(0,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) spends 1s if everything is correct, which include the network traffic time. Now network is down, given that ExponentialBackoffRetry(1000,3), so I compute the whole time it spent until it throw the exception and return false.
That is: 
1. retry 3 times : 1000ms*max(1,random(2))+1000ms*max(1,random(3))+1000ms*max(1,random(5))<=10s
2. network traffic:<=1s
so sum of the spent time is <=11s.
is that right? actually it spent almost 1min to return false.

Comment: I suggest you move this conversation to Curator's mailing list or open a ticket. SO is not a great forum for debugging your problem.